# how to develop android application that only run on one device at a time

Tags: android, imei

Developing Android application that run only on one device at a time.

User cannot use the application on multiple device not even use parallelspace.

What are my options?

Should I use IMEI or not?

Comment: Since each device has a unique MAC address, you could leverage that to help you solve this problem.

Comment: you mean that only one user can run only one instance? So if 10 people have your app, only one of them can use it simultanuously?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only reliable way to do this is have each user contact a server regularly (Firebase perhaps) in order to "register" itself as the currently allowed installation.

I have seen this with some games whereby any attempt to run the game twice for the same user causes an error message to be displayed.

You would need to have a "log out" mechanism but also allow for forced disconnect where an app crashes and there is no clean log out performed.  Maybe call to the server every 30 seconds or so to tell it that you are still in use on that device.

Regarding IMEI. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html